# Help in jquery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using JS fiddle for trying my hands on jquery validation. You can access the code at http://jsfiddle.net/8MmCS/3/ 

I am changing the background color of a control to 'red' if its validation fails. And if the data entered is validated, then the control border is changed to green.
But I need to change the border color to green , only if validation had failed previously.

Comment: That's what it's doing here, in Chrome...where are you having issues?

Comment: @Nick - I'm having the same problem that @vaibhav is having (using Firefox 3.6).

Comment: I want to show green color , only when validation had failed and while attempting to correct the data, user successfully validate the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change your unhighlight parameter to this:

```
unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        if($(element).hasClass('mandatory')) {
            $(element).removeClass('mandatory').addClass('success');
        }
    }
```

I updated your example here: http://jsfiddle.net/8MmCS/5/

Comment: @vaibhav - Glad I could help. If you don't mind, could you accept the answer as well? Would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to simply add a class for your green-state only if the field has a validation-failed-class already.